# applying an instruction immediately

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-mobile, optimization

On a button click handler, I am changing the appearance of this button by changing the class of the button.
Just after that, I'am refreshing a list with thousands of items, and this takes a little while (half a second approximately)

My problem is the appearance of the button is not changed immediately because of the long process that follows. (If I remove the process that follows, the change is immediate)

So, is there a way of forcing the first instruction (changing the appearance of the button) to be applied before the rest of the function is done.

```
      this.stopLoading = function (){
         this.isLoading = false;
       this.updateButtonLoading();
         this.updateObservers();
         this.endUpdate();//if i remove this the aspect of the button is changed immediatly
        }

      this.updateButtonLoading = function(){
        if(oSvdQueryList.curSvdQuery == this){

                 $("#btnLoading").removeClass();
                if (this.isLoading){
                         $("#btnLoading").addClass('stopLoading');
                     $("#btnLoading").bind('click', function (){ oSvdQueryList.curSvdQuery.stopLoading(); });
                }else
                    {
                         $("#btnLoading").addClass('startLoading');
                     $("#btnLoading").bind('click', function (){ oSvdQueryList.curSvdQuery.startLoading(); });

                    }
        }


      this.endUpdate = function(){
      this.fUpdate --;
      if (this.fUpdate == 0 ){

        setTimeout((function(self) {
      return function() { self.displayNewRecords() };
    })(this), 1);

      }
  }
   this.displayNewRecords = function(){      
     if ($.mobile.activePage.is("#DspQry") && oSvdQueryList.curSvdQuery == this ){
         for(var i= this.nbDisplayed; i< this.nbRecords;i++){
             addItem(this,i);
         }
        $("#ListDspQry").listview("refresh");
     } 

   }

function addItem(oSvdQuery,index){
    var html = '<li><a href="javascript:showDetails(' + (index) +')">';
    var oRecord = [];
    for (i=0;i<oSvdQuery.fields.length;i++){
        if ( oSvdQuery.fields[i].hidden !="Y") {
        oField = oSvdQuery.fields[i];
        oRecord= oSvdQuery.allValues[index];
        html = html + oField.name + ' : ' + oRecord[oField.name] + '<br>'; 

        }
    }
    html = html +  '</a></li>';
    $("#ListDspQry").append(html);
    oSvdQuery.nbDisplayed ++;

}
```

Comment: Please show your code .... the function of the button.

Comment: Put the long-running code in a `setTimeout()` with a very short duration. Like: `setTimeout(function() { /* slow code */ }, 10);`

Comment: hi, i've already tried the setTimeOut solution (sorry , i should have mentionned it) i'll put the code in a couple of minutes

Comment: @Arsnow: That should work. Try a longer duration if not. Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/atn5h/

Comment: Give the browser the time to draw: for a 30 fps the minimum time is 16.7 ms. If you give it 1 ms it has very few chances to draw. Try with 50 to have more chances...